# Show $\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\dfrac{z-x}{r}.\nabla u(z)dS(z)=\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}dS(z)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Show $\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\dfrac{z-x}{r}.\nabla u(z)dS(z)=\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}dS(z)$ where,

$u:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is smooth,

$\partial B(x,r)$ is the $n-1$-dimensional sphere centered at $x$ with radius $r$,

$\nu=\dfrac{z-x}{r}$ is the unit normal pointing outward at $z\in\partial B(x,r)$,

$dS$ is the surface element of the $n-1$-dimensional sphere.

Why is this formula true? I don't understand how the $\nu$ came to the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}$ they mean the derivative of $u$ in the normal direction, which can be computed as the gradient of $u$ dotted with the unit normal. It should be geometrically clear that for a sphere centered at $x$, the normal at a point $z$ on the surface points in the direction of the displacement from the center, that is $z-x$. Then you divide by $r$ to make make it unit length.